# Nexus 6 display performance, PWM and flickering

Tags: screen, hardware, motorola, nexus-6

Does anyone have any information about Nexus 6 (and its "brothers") real display performance? I'm worried about [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)/flickering, that usually exists in AMOLED displays and makes them completely unusable for me. (For example, all recent Samsung phones have flickering issue and because of that they are unusable). And Nexus 6 has AMOLED, if I understood right — but I couldn't find any details about it on the Internet yet.

It would be especially great if you have proofs (high-speed camera recordings, for example).

*A good article about what is PWM and how to test it:* http://tftcentral.co.uk/articles/pulse_width_modulation.htm

## Update

I've found this test result in a review:
[image: image from laptopmedia.com review]

It implies that above 30% brightness level the flickering must be (almost) absent. But it's not a complete answer, because

- it's unknown what's the real brightness at 30% and how much it differs from 100%, and is PWM completely inactive when brightness is above say 40% (the graphs show that at 30% there are indeed pulsations)
- is it possible to lock the brightness setting in such a way that it's forced to stay ≥ 40% for example

Comment: I don't own a Nexus 6, but you can disable auto-brightness in Android (Settings -> Display), and CyanogenMod (if not stock android - I can't confirm if it exists or not) has the property `ro.lcd_min_brightness` which can be set using `adb shell setprop`, and checked using `adb shell getprop`.

Comment: True, this simple option always exists. Automatic is better when it works, though. :) Interesting to know about the `ro.lcd_min_brightness`. I don't own a Nexus 6 too (hence the question), but just tried it on LG D856 (stock Android) — there's no such property.

Comment: Oh well. [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.gyrus.yaab&hl=en) seems to let you set minimum auto-brightness level, but I'm not entirely sure. Might be worth taking a look.

Comment: Hopefully this helps. I have a Nexus 6, and the display can get extremely bright if it needs to. 100% brightness on the nexus 6 is about 30% brighter than 100% on my Galaxy Note 10.1 2014. When under typical indoor lighting, I set the brightness between 35% and 50% (on adaptive display), to give you a reference. I've never noticed the screen flickering, but I've also never purposely checked for it.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like to know anything else. :)

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23 Thank you for the info. Well, what's really interesting is how _steady_ is the light output at different brightness levels — in other words, when it does flicker and when it does not. And many (if not most) people do not notice flickering even on things like 60Hz CRT displays, so this doesn't tell much, **but** it's easy to check, for example, by shooting it with video camera by both 50(or 25) and 60(or 30) FPS, or some other common techniques for testing flickering.

Comment: https://youtu.be/IHKWQRzS2tE — that's an example of a test with video recording

Comment: I think a valid question here is why does the screen flicker make the device unusable to you and if this can be fixed in some way.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos flickering is harmful to eyes and the brain, and causes fatigue. This is perfectly normal, most people just don't notice that or think that it cannot be better. (because A LOT of screens out there do flicker, and also there are a lot of crappy light bulbs that do flicker like crazy, too)

Comment: @SargeBorsch If most devices have this screen flicker, doesn't that mean that most are unusable to you? Sorry, but it seems your worrying about something that cannot really be avoided.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Most devices are definitely unusable. (Vendors care only about the 95% of population, who don't notice flicker OR don't realize it's harmful, because, ultimately, they care only about money) Fortunately, some of the devices are better, for example, I can say for sure that LG G3 doesn't suffer from this disease because I own it and never noticed it.

Comment: and it's certainly not only me, this is widely acknowledged fact: http://www.flatpanelshd.com/focus.php?subaction=showfull&id=1362457985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I saw Nexus 6P phone in action (it was one of the testing devices at work).

The results are, unfortunately, pretty bad: it indeed does flicker, flickering increases as the brightness decreases, and even at 100% brightness there is some flickering that's noticeable by naked eye.

Not sure if "regular" Nexus 6 (not 6P) is the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

Either steer clear of Amoled, or at 40% brightness use a screen filter app like Twilight to further reduce brightness without flickering. Contrast and colours may suffer though.

Comment: It was already clear that the phone flickers at 30% and less. But if you know something specific about the display performance in 40%..100% brightness range, then it'd deserve an answer.